# Is there a limit on how precise input range change/input events are in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a basic html slider that I need to be very precise (a small step value), ie.:

```
<input type="range" id="testRange" step="0.0000001" />
```

Whenever I try to attach to the value that is being output by the slider element, there seems to be a minimum delta 0.84 that I can never get lower, regardless of what my step value is (see https://jsfiddle.net/Lew2fmpw/ for an example, the delta is output in the console).

My question is whether I can do something to decrease this delta?

I've tried using the jquery on method like so:

```
$("#testRange").on("change input", updatee);
```

and I've tried using addEventListener, but the results are the same.

```
$("#testRange")[0].addEventListener("input", updatee);
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It's proportional to the size of the element. If you make the `<input>` like 30 or 40em wide, the intervals get a lot smaller.

Comment: Some browsers don't even allow `step` decimal values. You best bet is to use whole numbers and then divide that value by whatever factor you increased it by in the first place.